# how to open app when clicked on link which is shared in whatsapp or any social app through phonegap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

1)When i share a link through phonegap plugin to whatsapp. When user clicks on link. it should check whether a particular app is installed or not. If yes, open that link in the application or else open play store link showing to download the app

Answer (score 4):

The scenario you're describing, where the device intercepts an HTTP protocol link `http://example.com` (as opposed to a custom URL scheme using `example://`), is called ["Deep Linking"](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html) on Android and ["Universal Links"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) on iOS.

It's most easily achieved in a Cordova app for iOS and Android using the [cordova-universal-links-plugin](https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin) - full details and usage are on the plugin GitHub page.

I'm not aware of any currently existing plugins that make equivalent functionality available on the Windows platform

Comment: Hey, thank you for the response. Actually, i was trying to implement custom url plugin(https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme). When i am clicking the link, nothing is happening. i have put the handleURL function in document ready function. Should it be inside document ready or outside of it? I am using phone gap build!!!

Comment: One more thing, i was using social share plugin of whatsapp. When I shared a link like <a href="southplus://playvideo.html?videoid=1">test</a>.
It is going like "southplus://playvideo.html?videoid=1". It is not clickable. So   I created a static page in server(http://fornextit.com/south/test.html). I have put in an anchor tag in that sample page over server. Opened it in my mobile browser. When i clicked that link, my app is opening. However, I am not getting any alert, that i have kept in 'custom-url plugin' of phonegap in handleURL function.

Answer (score 1):

The standard solution to do mobile deep linking is now (on iOS9 and recent Android versions) the interception of `http` links by specific apps, as described in the answer by @DaveAlden...

However, that solution does not allow you to achieve exactly what you want, since users who do not have the target app installed are directed to the normal website instead of the app store...

To achieve what you want you have to implement *"old-style"* deep linking with a custom URL scheme and some Javascript magic. It is easiest to do this by using one of the many deep linking solutions, e.g. [deeplink.me](http://deeplink.me), [branch.io](http://branch.io) or [Shortcut Media](http://shortcutmedia.com) (disclaimer: I currently work for Shortcut Media).