# cordova app to start whatsapp

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I did a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103555/how-to-open-app-when-clicked-on-link-which-is-shared-in-whatsapp-or-any-social-a) [researches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218709/how-to-implement-facebook-send-twitter-share-send-sms-send-email-in-my-phoneg?rq=1) yet either the answer is outdated (cordova changed a lot since the answer) or in unanswered.

This is what i need:

I have a phone number on html page which is parte of a cordova app.

All that i need is to know how to send this number to whatsapp so either te user can add the number as contact and therefore be able to be prompted to send a message or simply open the message dialog.

Such behavior need to work on android and on ios too.

Any guidance is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are basically looking for sharing the data from your app to an other app (in this case whatsapp). I believe, social sharing plugin should help you out in this case which lets your share link, text and images to apps like facebook, whatsapp etc..

Please look at the [official social sharing plugin link](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin) for more info. Hope it helps.

Comment: Indeed @Gandhi it might solve my problem, however it could not be able to share something with someone not present on my contact list. maybe it's my workflow that is misconcepted.

Comment: @Sombriks May be you are rite. But ideally are you allowed to share something in whatsapp with out adding them into contact? Guess not.

Comment: @Sombriks i'm trying to do it with whatsapp-phonegap-plugin but i have to send SMS or invite the number first even if it registered. explain your solution please